# NSLayoutConstraint: Is it good practice (or not) to layout against views in stackview?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I have a horizontal stack view of images, below the stack view I need to show an arrow pointing to currently selected image (in the stack view), I thought since the views in stack view and the arrow image view have a common ancestor view, I should be able to pin the arrow to the horizontal center of the selected image view in the stack view. But is this a good practice? Is there a better way of doing this?

`Stack View: | IMG1 | IMG2 | IMG3 |
Arrow Icon:            |`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally fine to do - just verify that you don't have any conflicting constraints. Keep in mind that a stack view, in effect, generates constraints for its arranged subviews, so if you did something like (for example) set a fixed width for IMG1, it's possible you could run into constraint errors. But as long as you don't get any ambiguous or conflicting constraints, you're good to go.

The one alternative I could thing of is for each image (IMG1, IMG2, IMG3) to instead be a custom `UIView` subview, with some sort of `isCurrentlySelected` property to display the arrow.